# Error with CREATE DEFINER = root @ PROCEDURE

Tags: mysql, database-design, mariadb, heidisql

im getting an error in this script for my project. Im using MariaDB with HeidiSQL v12.2. I dont know what its happen with this script but the error occur at line 85. Sorry for my English.

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `SP_KPI_TIEMPO_SOLUCION`(
in pinicio datetime
,in pfin datetime
)
BEGIN
 select
sum(contador) as Total_Tickets
,sum(cumple) as Total_Cumple_SLA
,round(sum(cumple) / sum(contador) * 100) Kpi
/*,(
select color from colorkpi 
where
sum(cumple) / sum(contador)*100 >= rango1 and sum(cumple) / sum(contador)*100<rango2
) as Color*/
from
(

select 
 t.tn as ticket
 ,t.sla_id as id_tipo_sla
,s.name as nombre_sla
,1 as contador
,t.create_time 
,
(select min(tt.create_time) 
from ticket_history tt
,ticket_state e
where tt.ticket_id=t.id
and tt.article_id is not null
and tt.state_id=e.id
and tt.state_id<>1
/*and tt.state_id in (2,3,10,13,14)*/
and (e.type_id=3
or tt.state_id=14)) as cierre
,
case
when t.ticket_state_id=13 then 1 /*Cierre Técnico se considera como 1 cumple*/
else
case
when
s.solution_time>total_hh(DATE_FORMAT(t.create_time, "%Y,%m,%d %H,%i"), DATE_FORMAT((
select min(tt.create_time) 
from ticket_history tt
,ticket_state e
where tt.ticket_id=t.id
and tt.article_id is not null
and tt.state_id=e.id
and tt.state_id<>1
/*and tt.state_id in (2,3,10,13,14)*/
and (e.type_id=3
or tt.state_id=14) -- se agrega el esatdo solucionado como cerrado
), "%Y,%m,%d %H,%i")) then 1
else 0 end 
end
as Cumple

,s.solution_time

,total_hh(DATE_FORMAT(t.create_time, "%Y,%m,%d %H,%i"), DATE_FORMAT((
select min(tt.create_time) 
from ticket_history tt
,ticket_state e
where tt.ticket_id=t.id
and tt.article_id is not null
and tt.state_id=e.id
and tt.state_id<>1
/*and tt.state_id in (2,3,10,13,14)*/
and e.type_id=3
), "%Y,%m,%d %H,%i")) tiemporeal
from ticket t
,sla s
,ticket_state te
where
t.create_time between /*'2018/04/01 00:00'*/pinicio and /*'2018/04/30 23:59'*/pfin + interval 1439 minute 
and t.type_id in (1,8)/*8: Requerimiento 1:Indicente*/
and t.sla_id=s.id
and t.queue_id in (8) /*Solo mesa de ayuda*/
/*and t.ticket_state_id in (2,3,10,13,14,9) /*Estado Cerrados Solamente*/
and t.ticket_state_id=te.id
and te.type_id in (3,7) /* 3, cerrados - 7, fusionados*/
and te.valid_id=1
order by ticket    

)
a;

END
```

Hope someone can help me, Thanks!

Comment: I think you have forgotten to include the error message you are getting. It's really hard to see your screen from here. Also, which one is line 85? Surely, you don't expect us to count the lines ourselves. This is likely a [duplicate](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/180164/error-in-function-creating-query/180168#180168) too.

Comment: What tool are you using to perform the `CREATE`?

Comment: Do you have a `DELIMITER` statement?

Comment: Your SP contains only one statement. In this case BEGIN-END block is excess - remove it. *the error occur at line 85* This means that you have not reassigned DELIMITER. Or you have tried to create SP in the Query window, not in SP creation window.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in function creating query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/180164/error-in-function-creating-query)